# Passing an image URL from external API in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to use an external API which returns random image each time I visit it.

Example -

```
http://theapi.com/getimage
```

redirects to

```
http://somerandomsite/image.jpg
```

If I put just the API endpoint URL on its own the page renders the image only after I reload the page (at least in firefox). I can then keep reloading the page to get a new image each time. But if I go to a different page that also uses the same URL then the image is the same as the last one displayed on the previous page.

So. I am looking for a way to fetch URL to the image(that the API redirects to) and passing that directly from the view or the template.
The API ofcourse also has a JSON method which I can use. But is there a simpler way for just using the API URL and using something like url_for() in the template?

Comment: What's so complicated about the "json method"?

Comment: I am wondering if I did not have JSON option at all was this still doable. I am sure it is and will post a reply as soon as I have figured it out. I am new to both python and Flask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the solution I found --

```
import urllib2

url = "http://theapi.com/getimage"
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler)
request = opener.open(url)
return request.url
```